# How to give to a powershell variable only the output of my sqlplus query?

Tags: oracle, powershell, sqlplus

```
 $a = 'select 2 from dual' | sqlplus user/password@database.
```

expected result: 2

real result :

> SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue May 31 08:29:43 2022
> Version 19.3.0.0.0
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
> Last Successful login time: Tue May 31 2022 08:24:55 +02:00
> Connected to:
> Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
> Version 19.3.0.0.0
> SQL>   2
> SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
> Version 19.3.0.0.0

I would like to get only what my query returns. How do I do that?

---

@vonPrynz

$a = 'select 2 from dual' | sqlplus -S user/password@database.

result is empty

Comment: Try the `-s[ilent]` switch to tell [sqlplus](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch4.htm#1006198) not to print banners and such. That being said, consider using ODA.NET for [programmatic access](https://blog.darrenjrobinson.com/using-powershell-to-query-oracle-dbs-without-using-the-oracle-client-oracle-data-provider-for-net/) instead of passing parameters to a client app.

Comment: @vonPryz I have tried your solution. No result is returned

Comment: Oracle (clients) requires a semicolon for DML statements, so add one to the select query. That is, `'select 2 from dual;'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need add `';'`

```
PS C:\> 'select 2 as result from dual;' | sqlplus -s user/password@DEV19

    RESULT
----------
         2
```

If you want only '2' then add this lines:

```
'SET FEEDBACK OFF 
set heading off
set termout OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TAB OFF
set pause off
set verify off
SET UNDERLINE OFF
set trimspool on
set timing off
set echo off
set linesize 1000
set pagesize 100
select 2 as result from dual;' | sqlplus -s user/password@DEV19
     2
```